# xmppframework: iPhoneXMPP: RootController not updated with friend's presence

Tags: xmppframework

I tried the iPhoneXMPP demo but it seems that the GUI is not updated when my friend is online or offline. I modified the nsfetchresultcontroller to show online friend only:

```
...
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sectionNum == 0"]];
...
```

In xcode's console, it showed that it did receive the presences from my friends. But I saw that controllerDidChangeContent: is not get called at all. (Actually, I saw it's called sometimes, but randomly and rarely).

When I debugged more deeply, I saw that XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage handlePresence:xmppStream is called, then managedObjectContextDidSave:notification is called also. So everything seems right. But the resultfetchcontroller did not see the changes.

So what is the problem? Is there anything I did wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the code of the `fetchedResultsController` method.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your Predicate: It works just fine.

Did you initialize your NSFetchedResultsController correctly? You need to pass the NSManagedObjectContext of your XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage.

Comment: Yes, currently, I'm using [appDelegate managedObjectContext_roster] to init the fetch controller.